# Mautic API 403 error

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, mautic

SO when I try to get a refresh Token from Mautic I am getting an auth code but then from there I am not able to get an access/refresh token. When I try to get it I just receive a 403 error message with invalid code as the description.  Not sure what is going on!

Thanks
Cam